# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'GSRS.ussr' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. I am trying to create 3 tables as follows,

```
CREATE TABLE ur (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE sr (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

CREATE TABLE ussr (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT NOT NULL,
  service_id INT NOT NULL,
  speed_rating INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES ur.id,
  FOREIGN KEY(service_id) REFERENCES sr.id
);
```

I keep getting this error, "ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 12: Can't create table 'GSRS.ussr' (errno: 150)"

Can someone pls help me out?? :(
I'm using MySQL 14.14 on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  Should be `FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES ur (id)` rather than `REFERENCES ur.id` (same for `sr.id`, of course)

Comment: Thanks mate :) working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want

```
CREATE TABLE ussr (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT NOT NULL, service_id INT NOT NULL, speed_rating INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES ur (id), FOREIGN KEY(service_id) REFERENCES sr (id));
```

Comment: If it worked that you can accept it as your answer and upvote it

Comment: i am not able to do that.. it says i need 15 reputation to vote up... sorry :(